# How can I include the CSS file in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, html, css, codeigniter

I have make a assets folder in root directory where application folder exist. now I have assets sibling to application.

Now when I tried to open `http://localhost/CodeIgniter/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css` in web-page it's not working.

Do someone can help me how I can got it worked.

In a solution I found that writing this line in config file will work but it's not work either by doing this change.

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/CodeIgniter/';
```

Now please some guideline me how to load CSS file in CI.

solution :-

I have done something wrong in my codeigniter project. I download it again and try these thing again, without anything it's working.

thanks you all of guys. you save my time.

Comment: Try this: http://glennstovall.com/blog/2012/02/28/setting-up-a-template-and-assets-in-codeigniter/

Comment: You have not mentioned how exactly you tried other than the config variable setting. :)

Comment: Also as it seems you are a beginner in CI, I would recommend you to watch the screencasts on nettuts.com "CodeIgniter from scratch series".

Comment: load URL helper. $this->load->helper('url');

Comment: @SibirajPR thanks I have tried it as echo base_url()/myfileurl but it's look like no url work for get the file.

Comment: `$this->load->helper("url");`

and in view:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url()?>asset/css/bốtstrap.min.css" type="text/css">`

if its still not working, post all your code here.


** I'm bad English, so sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

define general css that used. 
Open "config.php" within directory CodeIgniter\system\application\config.

```
$config['css'] = 'mystyles.css';
```

Create a file named mystyles.css within root application: \CodeIgniter.

```
$this->load->helper('url');       
$data['css']        = $this->config->item('css');
```

You can load css in views pages like this.

Answer (score 13):

**In constant.php:**

```
define('URL','http://localhost/CodeIgniter/');
define('IMG',URL.'assets/img/');
define('CSS',URL.'assets/css/');
define('JS',URL.'assets/js/');
```

**In config.php:**

```
$config['base_url'] = URL;
```

**In view:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo(CSS.'bootstrap.min.css'); ?>">
```

Hope that helps somewhat.

Comment: what is URL in config.php file ?

Answer (score 1):

Add below line in your controller action /application/controllers/yourController.php

```
$this->load->helper('url');
```

Then add below line to your view file's head tag.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<? echo base_url('assets/css/yourcssfile.css');?>" />
```

Assuming that you have assets/css/ folder is created in your app directory.

```
<path to your app folder>/assets/css
```