# How can I include css and js file in codeigniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I am trying toinclude css file in the following code.

Config :

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/ASOFT/Projects/CI_search';
$config['site_url'] = 'http://localhost/ASOFT/Projects/CI_search/index.php';
$config['js'] = 'assets/js';
```

View:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $base?>/<?php echo $css?>/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $base?>/<?php echo $css?>/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="<?php echo $base?>/<?php echo $js?>/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo $base?>/<?php echo $js?>/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo $base?>/<?php echo $js?>/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

I put the css file in CI_search/css  and js file in CI_search/assets/js
I got the  error  undefined variable css and  undefined variable js.Please provide solution for this problem.

---

**UPDATE**

Controller:

```
public function index() {     
    $this->data = array(
         'site' => $this->config->item('site_url'), 
         'base' => $this->config->item('base_url'), 
         'css' => $this->config->item('css'), 
         'js' => $this->config->item('js'), 
         'image'=>$this->config->item('image') 
    ); 

   $data = $this->data; 
   $data['error'] = ''; 

   $this->load->view('index',$data); 
}
```

Comment: where are `$base` , `$css`, `$js` defined?

Comment: dont you need this `$this->config->item('item name');` somewhere in your code?

Comment: CodieGodie    $base , $css, $js are defined in controller    $this->data = array(
  'site' => $this->config->item('site_url'),
         'base' => $this->config->item('base_url'),
         'css' => $this->config->item('css'),
          'js' => $this->config->item('js'),
  'image'=>$this->config->item('image')
        );

Comment: how are you passing your data to your view? is it still not working?

Comment: CodieGodie    public function index()
 {
  $data=$this->data;
  $data['error']=''; 
  $this->load->view('index',$data);
  }

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I include the CSS file in CodeIgniter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14008832/how-can-i-include-the-css-file-in-codeigniter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as i can see, you din't declared $config['css'] in your config file, so it's normal to get undefined variable error for css. But you shouldn't have problem with js.

When declaring your base_url use trailing slash at the end (eg. "http://localhost/fancysite/")

Also you can use CI's url helper to use functions like base_url() or site_url() and many more. (as @Likee suggested).

**config.php**

```
// this should be the first variable in CI's config.php
$config['base_url'] = "http://localhost/ASOFT/Projects/CI_search/";

// many more lines with other configuration variables
// ..................................................
// ..................................................
// ..................................................

// your own configuration variables at the end of file
$config['css'] = 'css/';
$config['js'] = 'assets/css/';
$config['image'] = 'images/';
```

**controller**

```
public function index() {

    // loading url helper to use base_url() function in the view,
    // if you load this helper in autoload.php you don't need to load it here again
    $this->load->helper('url');

    // if you didn't declare data as class property
    // you can simply use
    // $data = array(
    //         'css' => $this->config->item('css'),
    //         'js' => $this->config->item('js'),
    //         'image'=>$this->config->item('image')
    //          );

    $this->data = array( 
         'css' => $this->config->item('css'), 
         'js' => $this->config->item('js'), 
         'image'=>$this->config->item('image') 
    ); 

    // you really don't need the line below
    // $data = $this->data;
    $this->data['error'] = ''; 

    $this->load->view('index',$this->data); 
}
```

**view**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url($css . 'style.css'); ?>">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url($css . 'bootstrap.min.css'); ?>">
<script src="<?php echo base_url($js . 'jquery.min.js'); ?>"></script>
<!-- do you really need to include jquery.js while you included jquery.min.js above? but here we go :) -->
<script src="<?php echo base_url($js . 'jquery.js'); ?>"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url($js . 'bootstrap.min.js'); ?>"></script>
```

Probably you will need to use url helper a lot. So you can autoload it in autoload.php file in config folder. it must be somewhere around line 90

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to include css and js file in codeigniter.
This how I do it.

FIRST: Create a folder outside the application folder and named it any named you liked but I prefer to named it as resources. Create a sub folders like js, css, images and others. Place all your files in here for future references.

SECOND: Open the the contants.php saved in application/config and paste this code.

```
define('CSS',       'http://localhost/yourfolder/resources/css');
define('JS',        'http://localhost/yourfolder/resources/js');
define('IMAGES',    'http://localhost/yourfolder/resources/images');
```

NOTE: Update this code depends on your needs.

THIRD: On your view file, you can access this files by,

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo(CSS.'bootstrap.min.css'); ?>">
<script type="text/javascript" src='<?php echo(CSS.'bootstrap.min.css'); ?>'></script>
```

Refer to this link. [How can I include the CSS file in CodeIgniter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14008832/how-can-i-include-the-css-file-in-codeigniter)

I hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

Bind your variables to view like this:

```
$this->load->view('viewName', $config);
```

And array $config should be available in your controller method.

Instead setting $config['base_url'] you can use function base_url().

Answer (score 0):

well if at all possible determine what your path structure will be and then just use it in the view with base_url() .

```
<link href="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/js/blahblah.js"></script>
```

you can even have a few simple templates, and then call the appropriate template.

if that is impossible - then push this logic and output to a model or similar so that it can be called by different controllers. otherwise you are going to have to update folder names and file paths in your controllers.